# Making the latest post styled different than other posts

Tags: php, html, css

This is my first time on here so apologies if something like this has been asked before.

My current sites has 2 posts per row but I want the first/latest post to be styled slightly different.

Basically I want the first/latest post to be 100% wide on the page then all the other posts to follow, 2 per row but only on the home page. Category pages etc I'm happy for that to stay 2 per row.

My current code is:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<article class="post-item clearfix" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<figure>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('single-post-feature'); ?></a>

</figure>

<header>

<div class="post-header-title">

<div class="post-category-feature">
        <?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>
            </div>

<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '<h1>'; } else { echo '<h2>'; } ?><span><a class="black" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span><?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '</h1>'; } else { echo '</h2>'; } ?>

<div id="excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>

<div id="author_date"><p><span><?php the_time('jS F Y') ?> | by <?php the_author(''); ?></span></p></div>

</div>  

</header>

</article>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you would like to see the site to understand what I mean it is [www.ltstlife.com](http://www.ltstlife.com). Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have a specific class that makes such a post go 100% wide? Then just add that, for the the first post you output in that loop. If the posts are all grouped inside a container element, you can also use the `:first-child` pseudo class in your stylesheet to only target the first one of them, and style it differently.

Comment: FYI, the `post_class` function outputs a complete `class` attribute already, so with the code you currently have, you are outputting _two_ `class` attributes on the article element, which is invalid HTML. You should feed your additional classes into this function as first parameter instead.

Comment: Thank you misorude! Did the first-class pseudo and that works perfectly as they are grouped inside a container element. Appreciated!

Comment: So if I take out <?php post_class(); ?> would this make a difference. I dont think it will as I tried it and it didnt look like anything changed on the site. I didnt write this bit of code btw. Im not entirely sure what class="post-item clearfix" actually does as there isnt anything called this in my CSS

Comment: `post_classes` outputs a couple of default classes, depending on where a post is shown, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Default_Values If you are not on any of those pages, it probably will not output anything at all, and do no harm in this instance. But in general, you should add your own “static” classes (`post-item clearfix`) by passing them to this function, otherwise you might get a situation where the HTML output generated becomes `<article class="post-item clearfix" id="post-123" class="{wp-classes}">`.